# Overriding Global Variables Used in Class Definition When Creating Subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, module, global-variables

My apologies if this question has already been answered, I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

I've downloaded a package off the internet and it has a class, say `Bicycle` that I want to create a subclass of. `Bicycle` uses global variables declared locally in `bicycle.py`, as below:

```
COLOR_DICT = { "blue" : 0, "green" : 1, "red" : 2}

class Bicycle:

    ...    

    def encode(self):
        return (self.name, self.height, COLOR_DICT[self.color])
```

I want to subclass bicycle, say with a Tricycle class, and I want to retain much of the functionality (and most of the global variables) defined in `bicycle.py`, but I want to use a different `COLOR_DICT`. If I wanted `encode` to use my different `COLOR_DICT` would I have to override encode locally in my tricycle file, even though the code will be exactly the same? If I just redefine `COLOR_DICT` in the new file I assume the superclass still references the one defined in its file.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide your own `encode()` function. Global variables are global, they affect all code.

Comment: If the designer of the Bicycle class wanted to make it more customizable in subclasses, they would have made `COLOR_DICT` a class variable rather than global.

Comment: @Barmar Definitely, part of why I was confused is I would never do things this way ;)